# MIMIC-III cancelreason meaning

Tags: mimic-iii

In the MIMIC-III database, when describing the variable CANCELREASON in tables INPUTEVENTS_MV or INPUTEEVENTS_CV, the text says:

"CANCELREASON"
                        ],
"If the order was canceled, this column provides some explanation."

But I can not see any explanation, only a numerical coding 0, 1 or 2.

Does anyone know the meaning of 0, 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not clear. In theory, the coded integer would reference another table in the source database which would explain what 0, 1, or 2 means. In practice, I couldn't find any table which fit, and there was no documentation available for guidance. Rather than invent something, it's left as it was in the source data.